# How to get street directions in google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-street-view

I want to display street directions from my current location to particular known location(latitude and longitude), how to do it using google map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that till android 1.6, they have removed the street directions after those versions.

Use the below code to get the activity in higher than android 1.6 versions.
Hope this helps you.

`final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" +"saddr="+sourcelatitudeString+","+sourcelongitudeString+"&daddr="+sourcelatString+","+sourcelongString));
                    intent.setClassName(
                             "com.google.android.apps.maps",
                             "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                              startActivity(intent);`

Comment: what is saddr and daddr refer to? which one is current and which on is destination? please let me know

Comment: @Vamshi saddr refers to source address and daddr refers to destination address.

Comment: OK i will test it and if it is working i will accept your answer thanks

Comment: if i want route to location then is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: @Vamshi can you elaborate, you already get route their right, are you asking is their another way to get route, yes you can display route but no route directions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to frame a URL and send via HTTP connection to get all driving directions in a single output file. Google provides some file formats to receive driving directions information. One of them is KML file.

See below link to get an idea.

[Sample Google Map Driving Direction.](http://about-android.blogspot.in/2010/03/sample-google-map-driving-direction.html)